# Snap() method causes Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, undefined, snap.svg, typeerror

I'm using Snapsvg (http://snapsvg.io/) and I'm getting a basic "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the line where  var s = Snap("#svgout"); is defined. I know this means that the browser doesn't know what "Snap" is. My HTML is loading the snap.svg.js before I'm calling it in my script.js file. I'm starting to think this might be a bug. Any suggestions to debug or thoughts on what can be causing it?

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Framework Template</title>
<script src="assets/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<!--<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

<link href="assets/css/stylesDevelopment.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
 <body>
 <section class="container">
<section class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="title">Let's Begin ...</h2>
        <div id="svgout">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/snap.svg.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

//scripts.js file

```
$(function(){

  var s = Snap("#svgout");
```

//lets draw 2 rects at position 100,100 and then reposition them

```
  var r = s.rect(100,100,100,100,20,20).attr({ stroke: '#123456', 'strokeWidth': 20, fill: 'red', 'opacity': 0.2 });

  var t = s.text(100,50,'Snap("#svg") should reference an svg element, not a div. Or create it by supplying width,height Snap(100,100)');


});
```

Comment: can you post some code (the HTML and JS) or link to it? it would be much easier to help

Comment: This happens a lot with `.js` libraries. From first glance, it looks like everything is being loaded in the proper order, but make sure any files that are required for the `Snap()` method are included *before* calling it. Again, it looks correct, but there might be something out of place. My first though is don't have `<script src="assets/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>` in the `<head>`, but with your other `.js` files. Or maybe it's because you have both the `min` and `non-min` ones included.

Comment: Actually, that's a typo. I tried putting it in the head when the body didn't work. Makes no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue is in the text :). If you look at this line (I wrote it in the original example to help, but I guess its ignored :))...

```
  var t = s.text(100,50,'Snap("#svg") should reference an svg element, not a div. Or create it by supplying width,height Snap(100,100)');
```

Its saying that Snap takes an SVG element, NOT a div.

So you should swap the div for svg in this line.

```
  <div id="svgout">
    </div>
```

to

```
      <svg id="svgout">
    </svg>
```

Comment: I'm gasped it's right in the javaScript. I can't believe I over looked that. Thank you.